# How do I implement simple pop up guide as shown in attached image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a pop up guide in flutter to indicate what a user needs to do e.g button to click. What widget can I use with a code snippet to implement this? Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

i'm never used the package but it's looking promising

https://github.com/blackmenthor/flutter-introduction-tooltip

Comment: Thanks fyrok1 for the answer, what the package does is not the same as what I intends to implement, thanks anyway.